Why can't I wrap LGBM?
I'm using LGBM to forecast the relative change of a numerical quantity. I'm using the MSLE (Mean Squared Log Error) loss function to optimize my model and to get the correct scaling of errors. Since MSLE isn't native to LGBM, I have to implement it myself. But lucky me, the math can be simplified a ton. This is my implementation;
class MSLELGBM(LGBMRegressor):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.exp(super().predict(X))
    
    def fit(self, X, y, eval_set=None, callbacks=None):
        y_log = np.log(y.copy())
        print(super().get_params())  # This doesn't print any kwargs
        if eval_set:
            eval_set = [(X_eval, np.log(y_eval.copy())) for X_eval, y_eval in eval_set]
        super().fit(X, y_log, eval_set=eval_set, callbacks=callbacks)

As you can see, it's very minimal. I basically just need to apply a log transform to the model target, and exponentiate the predictions to return to our own non-logarithmic world.
However, my wrapper doesn't work. I call the class with;
model = MSLELGBM(**lgbm_params)
model.fit(data[X_cols_all], data[y_col_train]) 

And I get the following exception;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 38
     32 callbacks = [
     33     lgbm.early_stopping(10, verbose=0), 
     34     lgbm.log_evaluation(period=0),
     35 ]
     37 model = MSLELGBM(**lgbm_params)
---> 38 model.fit(data[X_cols_all], data[y_col_train]) 
     40 feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame([model.booster_.feature_importance(importance_type='gain')], columns=X_cols_all).T.sort_values(by=0, ascending=False)
     41 feature_importances_df.iloc[:30]

Cell In[31], line 17
     15 if eval_set:
     16     eval_set = [(X_eval, np.log(y_eval.copy())) for X_eval, y_eval in eval_set]
---> 17 super().fit(X, y_log, eval_set=eval_set, callbacks=callbacks)

File c:\X\.venv\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py:1189, in LGBMRegressor.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, init_score, eval_set, eval_names, eval_sample_weight, eval_init_score, eval_metric, feature_name, categorical_feature, callbacks, init_model)
   1172 def fit(  # type: ignore[override]
   1173     self,
   1174     X: _LGBM_ScikitMatrixLike,
   (...)
   1186     init_model: Optional[Union[str, Path, Booster, LGBMModel]] = None,
   1187 ) -> "LGBMRegressor":
   1188     """Docstring is inherited from the LGBMModel."""
...
--> 765 if isinstance(params["random_state"], np.random.RandomState):
    766     params["random_state"] = params["random_state"].randint(np.iinfo(np.int32).max)
    767 elif isinstance(params["random_state"], np.random.Generator):

KeyError: 'random_state'

I have no idea how random_state is missing from the fit method, as it isnt even required for that function. I get the impression that this is a complicated software engineering issue that's above my head. Anybody knows whats up?
If it's of any help, I tried illustrating what I want using a simpler non-lgbm structure;

I just want to pass whatever parameters I provide to the MSLELGBM to the original LGBM, but I'm running into a ton of issues doing so.
